# Failing anchor in Firefox (html)

Tags: html, firefox, anchor

In run in to some trouble with referring to an anchor at another page.
In Chrome it works in the way I expect it to work, however it won't work in Firefox.
The problem occurs on the page from the following link and then the link in the last line, called 'Artikel 8'. 
https://toernooi.skeuvel.nl/programma/

The idea is that it goes to 'https://toernooi.skeuvel.nl/reglementen/' and scrolls down to 'Artikel 8'. Someone who can tell me how to fix this problem?

I'm not having much experience with html...
The page is in dutch, but that won't be a problem the understand the question I think...

Answer (score 0):

In your anchor you are referring to a URL with an appended `.html` suffix. Remove that so the link is like so:

```
<a href="https://toernooi.skeuvel.nl/reglementen/#art8">Artikel 8</a>
```

Be aware that when a page scrolls down to a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), it can only go so far as the height of the page allows. In its current form, the page you are linking to is not heigh enough for the fragment identifier to position itself optimally.

Comment: I already tried the link you said... Won't work also. I know that won't work optimally, but it has to scroll down to the botom at least...
For example, it does work inside the 'reglementen' page!
Another good idea?

Comment: @Ruben I can see you have changed it to my suggestion and it is definitely working for me on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. My only suggestion would be for you to clear your cache...

Comment: I cleared the cache and restarted Firefox... Still the same problem. It just goes to the 'reglementen' page at the top.
Even adding 100 empty paragraphs below, wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Ruben I don't know what else to suggest. It is working for me every time. What version of Firefox are you using, and what operating system?

Comment: Firefox 35.0 - Windows 7. I also tried at Firefox 35.0 at Windows 8.1. Same problem, not going down to 'Artikel 8'...
When clicking the link and press the enter-key in the adress bar, it will work...

Comment: @Ruben I am seeing the error in Firefox again now. Have you tried removing the domain-name part of the URL in the previous page? So it becomes `<a href="/reglementen/#art8">Artikel 8</a>`...

Comment: I didn't, but now I did... Nothing changes, problem still te same for me. 
It's not worth to discuss hours and hours about this, so feel free to say: I don't know it yet :P 
Site is functional, it's just the icing on the cake!

Comment: Maybe it is the same problem as this:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645075

Comment: @Ruben Yeah I saw that earlier. But it was reported in Firefox 4 so I figured  that they would have fixed it by now. Anyway, report back if you find a solution - I'd be interested to know what it is.

Comment: Last comment in that post in from this year, so may be a problem right now! End of discussion...